# A bug in FFT Algorithm

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fft

my friends, I am programming FFT algorithm now and I have the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<complex>
#include<cmath>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const complex<double> I(0,1);
const int pi = M_PI;

//This function will check if a number is a power of certain number 
bool checkpower(float base,float num){
    float a = ceil(log(num)/log(base))-floor(log(num)/log(base));
    if (a==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
    return 0;
    }
}


//Fast Fourier Transform for DFT
vector<complex<double>> FFT_DFT(vector<complex<double>> samples){
    int N = samples.size();
    cout << N << endl;
    if(!checkpower(2,N)){
        cout << "Please make sure the sample size is of 2^n!" << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        vector<complex<double>> F(N);
        if(N==1){
            F.push_back(samples[0]);
        }
        else{
            int M = N/2;
            cout << M << endl;
            vector<complex<double>> O; //vector to store the odd elements
            vector<complex<double>> E; //vector to store the even elements
            //Reoder the samples
            for(int l=0;l<M;l++){
                E.push_back(samples[2*l]);
                O.push_back(samples[2*l+1]);
            }
            vector<complex<double>> ODFT;
            cout << "Start recursive for odd" << endl;
            ODFT = FFT_DFT(O);
            vector<complex<double>> EDFT;
            cout << "Start recursive for even" << endl;
            EDFT = FFT_DFT(E);
            for(int k=0;k<M;k++){
                cout << real(EDFT[k]) << " + "<< imag(EDFT[k]) << "I" << endl;
                cout << real(ODFT[k]) << " + "<< imag(ODFT[k]) << "I" << endl;
                F[k] = EDFT[k]+exp(-2.0*pi*k*I/(double)N)*ODFT[k];
                F[k+M] = EDFT[k]-exp(-2.0*pi*k*I/(double)N)*ODFT[k]; 
                cout << real(F[k]) << " + "<< imag(F[k]) << "I" << endl;
                cout << real(F[k+M]) << " + "<< imag(F[k+M]) << "I" << endl;
            }
        }
        return F;
    }
}


int main(){
    vector<complex<double>> samples;
    samples.push_back(8.0);
    samples.push_back(4.0);
    samples.push_back(8.0);
    samples.push_back(0.0);

    vector<complex<double>> dft = FFT_DFT(samples);
    vector<complex<double>>::iterator item;

    for(item=dft.begin();item!=dft.end();item++){
        cout << real(*item) << " + "<< imag(*item) << "I" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I use visual studio 2010 professional as compiler. I don't know what is wrong in my recursive algorithm, so I used the debug mode in VS and I checked the procedure line by line, but it seems it always gave me 0 for all values. And I test it with normal FFT algorithm, it works perfect.  So, can anyone help me have a look on my program? I have debug this for around 4 hours and still can't find the bug. Perhaps, I did something very stupid and I didn't notice.

(Just for your notice,in the FFT function, in order to see what really happened, I also add many cout lines)

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Please post your code here.  (To format it, just select it, and click the **{}** button in the question editor.)

Comment: Do you know how to insert a whole block of code? I only know how to insert code line by line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
F.push_back(samples[0]);
```

which adds an element to `F` - which already has one element, zero - with

```
F[0] = samples[0];
```

You're ending your recursion with a vector that has a zero as its first element and a sample as its second.
Since you later only use the first element, everything becomes zero.

Comment: Thanks, dude! This fixed the program immediately! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I can't immediately say what your problem is, but you have at least one serious bug. Here:

```
float a = ceil(log(num)/log(base))-floor(log(num)/log(base));
if (a==0){
    return 1;
}
```

Other than the fact that a valid comparison would be to `0.0f`, you **should not** do some floating point calculation and expect the value to be a specific number. Where you expect `0.0`, it may actually be something like `0.00000000132`. Because that is [how floating point numbers work](http://floating-point-gui.de/). They always have and will work like that, unfortunately.

As for your FFT calculation, I'd look more closely at the lines where you assign `F[k]` and `F[k+M]`. In those, you multiply a value by `ODFT[k]` and my suspicion is that `ODFT[k]` may be `0` there.

Comment: Sorry, you can ignore this function, because I intensively tested and it worked. (it just return the true value if a number is a power of some number, so (2,4) will give true value, and (2,5) won't) And if we restrict our input, we can also delete this checking in the FFT function, so the main question is about FFT algorithm part

Comment: This function doesn't work. It can not, and unless you understand it, you will never be able to correctly program a mathematical algorithm. Try it with `(7, 2401)` or with `(0.35, 0.042875)`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify clearly, although I declared it as an float but I will only input integers, because that's what I need in FFT algorithm. And I don't know which compiler you use, but (7,2401) works perfect in my Visual studio, and it returned me 1.

Comment: @Cancan those two I mentioned were failing examples from a quick test with gcc on a 64-bit platform. The exact values where it fails may also vary, which only makes such a function even worse. As for your FFT calculation, I'd look more closely at the lines where you assign `F[k]` and `F[k+M]`. In those, you multiply a value by `ODFT[k]` and my suspicion is that `ODFT[k]` may be `0` there.

Comment: As I mentioned, the compiler is different, but I do admit my checkpower function has bug, but please forget about it, because the use of this function is just to check if the input array is a size of 2 to the power of something or not. So, please, please forget about it. :) And it would be nice if you can have look more on the FFT part, thanks!

Comment: I just did, please take a look at the second half of my last comment and edited answer :) I haven't run your code but that looks like the place it could be failing.